# Macbook pro reboot questions

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro

i went to use my macbook pro and it appeared with a blinking question mark i got past that page to the OS X Utilities but how do i reboot it without losing everything i have? I don't have a disc or a time machine backup.

Answer (score 1):

OK, blinking ? mark means it lost your boot sector.

Sometimes that can be easy repaired by using the OS X restore function.

Press and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> during the start up to get in to the recovery mode.

Pending your computer type and age it might have it already on your hard disk and it will use it to repair your OS X without impacting your personal files.